# Calling static method using class name - Good or Bad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-methods, class-method

I am getting more and more familiar with static methods and class methods and I know the difference between each. But I ran into a problem today where I would kind of like to reference both `self` **and** `cls` in a method.

The only way I know how to accomplish this is to make a normal class method (not with `@classmethod`, but simply with `def`) and call the class with it's name explicitely like so:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__():
        self._ser.connect('COM5')

    def ask(self, message: str) -> str:
        return myClass.clean_output(self._ser.query(message))

    @staticmethod
    def clean_output(dirty_string: str):
        clean_string = dirty_string.strip().replace(chr(4))
        return clean_string
```

This example is an over-simplified version of the philosophy. I would like to call a clean or parse function on data I get back, like from a serial device. Is there any way to implement the ask method like so?:

```
    def ask(self, message: str) -> str:
        return cls.clean_output(self._ser.query(message))
```

Or is it ok that I'm calling it with `myClass` explicitly like that? If it is, when should programmers use `@classmethod` and when is it permissible to use the class name itself? Is using the `@classmethod` decorator only really needed when you expect subclassing to happen?

Answer (score 4):

Just call the static method on `self`:

```
def ask(self, message: str) -> str:
    return self.clean_output(self._ser.query(message))
```

It is available there too.

Attributes on a class are always available on the instances too (provided there is no attribute on the instance itself with the same name masking it). Methods (be they regular, static or class methods) are no exception, they too are just attributes. Their binding behaviour doesn't matter here.

Comment: Ah geez... That was too simple. Thanks for it though. Is this information published anywhere? I looked but maybe I didn't ask google the right question. It makes complete sense that instances would also have class methods. Doh!

Comment: @boymeetscode: I've added why they are available; staticmethod objects are not special here, so there won't be any dedicated documentation to point to there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `cls` alongside `self`, then `self.__class__` does just the thing. However, as Martijn pointed out, it isn't really necessary here. But if you have to access the class inside instance method though, then use `self.__class__` :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34733593)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).